# Lean & mean, basic SMTP server, for use over a single domain, no fwd'ing

Tags: smtp, domain, forwarding, lightweight, smtpd

Looking for recommendation for a light-weight, SMTP server, with basic capabilities (will be run on port#25, with authentication but clear-channel), and it's use shall be limited to a particular (or a small set of) domain(s), i.e. mail to/from same set of domain(s) for authenticated members (both to/from fields) only shall be accepted, and of course, with additional spam filtering (bayesian possibly).

Target platform is Ubuntu Server (10.04.01) / CentOS 5.5.

TIA,
~i++

Comment: BTW, I found a python project, called LamsonProject. Looks promising and simple, although I'm having a hard time configuring it to listen on the machine IP. even after changing it's config & restarting, netstat -a tells me that dude is still listening on localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 2):

I also think postfix is a good solution for you.  If you find you need an easy to manage spam filter solution take a look at this: http://assp.sourceforge.net/

Checkout this great guide as well: http://howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-ubuntu-10.10

Comment: thanks @pablo. That's a great suggestion, and pretty close to what i need, with the virtual users. i hope i figure out how to limit SMTP forwarding to just the single domain. reading plain postfix documentation was a bit too much. virtual **vote up** (not enough reps).

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would use postfix, it's one of the most flexible SMTP servers on the market, with great guides all around the internet and a huge user base, you can't really go wrong with it, it also comes as a pre-packaged option both for Ubuntu Server and CentOS.

If you want to get a bit more advanced you can always go to sendmail, but considering your requirements postfix is a perfect fit.

Comment: Thanks @lynxman. Following your suggestion I started reading up on how to configure postfix, but the material seems to vast. I wish there were some simple wizard style tools to configure it.